# How to speedup screenshot capture of an rtsp stream via ffmpeg?

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I want to capture a fresh screenshot from an rtsp stream and pass the data on via php whenever an ajax endpoint is called.

Currently I am simply running

```
$resp = exec( 'ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -y -i '.$post['link'].' -vframes 1 '.$path.$imagename);
```

The problem is this takes a lot of time to generate a screenshot, about 4 second per capture if the stream is good. If the stream drops frames or causes an error, I won't get a response and the script will timeout.

Is there a way to optimize this or allow for fault tolerance? And overall speedup things so I can get a screenshot every second? If there's a better solution over ffmpeg, I am willing to try it as well!

Comment: What is the keyframe interval?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, it's a continuous video stream from an IP camera, and I need to grab a screenshot every second from it.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
ffmpeg -i "rtsp://192.168.1.73/live/ch00_1" -s 320x240 -f image2 -vf fps=fps=3 /tmp/ipcam_73_%04d.jpg
```

*(example generates 3 images per second)*

Comment: It would be nice to understand why this is a recommendation here.